# When to use NSURLSessionDownloadTask and NSURLSessionDataTask?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessiondatatask

What is the difference between these 2. I am able to get the data from the server using both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between NSURLSessionDataTask vs NSURLSessionDownloadTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604910/what-is-difference-between-nsurlsessiondatatask-vs-nsurlsessiondownloadtask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of concrete session tasks in this context:

NSURLSessionDataTask: Use this task for HTTP GET requests to retrieve data from servers to memory.

NSURLSessionUploadTask: Use this task to upload a file from disk to a web service, typically via a HTTP POST or PUT method.

NSURLSessionDownloadTask: Use this task to download a file from a remote service to a temporary file location.

You can also suspend, resume and cancel tasks. NSURLSessionDownloadTask has the additional ability to pause for future resumption.[image]